# `./manage.py migrate` fails with Postgresql while applying migrations for a built-in Django app

Tags: django, postgresql

The built-in Django app that fails to migrate seems to be `django.contrib.sites`. Here's the full output of `./manage.py migrate`:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, contenttypes, leasikApp, sessions, sites, socialaccount
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying account.0001_initial... OK
  Applying account.0002_email_max_length... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length... OK
  Applying leasikApp.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sites.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sites.0002_alter_domain_unique... OK
  Applying socialaccount.0001_initial... OK
  Applying socialaccount.0002_token_max_lengths... OK
  Applying socialaccount.0003_extra_data_default_dict... OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abhishek/.local/share/virtualenvs/leasik-iCbC7nbs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.errors.NumericValueOutOfRange: setval: value 0 is out of bounds for sequence "django_site_id_seq" (1..2147483647)


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "./manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/abhishek/.local/share/virtualenvs/leasik-iCbC7nbs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/abhishek/.local/share/virtualenvs/leasik-iCbC7nbs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/abhishek/.local/share/virtualenvs/leasik-iCbC7nbs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/abhishek/.local/share/virtualenvs/leasik-iCbC7nbs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 417, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/abhishek/.local/share/virtualenvs/leasik-iCbC7nbs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 90, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/abhishek/.local/share/virtualenvs/leasik-iCbC7nbs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 277, in handle
    emit_post_migrate_signal(
  File "/home/abhishek/.local/share/virtualenvs/leasik-iCbC7nbs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 46, in emit_post_migrate_signal
    models.signals.post_migrate.send(
  File "/home/abhishek/.local/share/virtualenvs/leasik-iCbC7nbs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 170, in send
    return [
  File "/home/abhishek/.local/share/virtualenvs/leasik-iCbC7nbs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 171, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "/home/abhishek/.local/share/virtualenvs/leasik-iCbC7nbs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/management.py", line 38, in create_default_site
    cursor.execute(command)
  File "/home/abhishek/.local/share/virtualenvs/leasik-iCbC7nbs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/abhishek/.local/share/virtualenvs/leasik-iCbC7nbs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/abhishek/.local/share/virtualenvs/leasik-iCbC7nbs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/abhishek/.local/share/virtualenvs/leasik-iCbC7nbs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/abhishek/.local/share/virtualenvs/leasik-iCbC7nbs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/abhishek/.local/share/virtualenvs/leasik-iCbC7nbs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 83, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.DataError: setval: value 0 is out of bounds for sequence "django_site_id_seq" (1..2147483647)
```

These are all built-in migrations being applied, except for `leasikApp.0001_initial`, which is applied successfully.

The problem seems to be that the default value of `site_id` is 0 while Postgresql wants `site_id` to be in the range (1..2147483647). But this is an error due to a built-in Django app. Is there something I can do to fix this?

**Update**: Model definitions for `leasik`:

```py
class Sentence(models.Model):
    """A sentence with a text and translation."""

    text = models.TextField()
    translation = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('text', 'translation')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.text} ({self.translation})'

class SentenceList(models.Model):
    """A list of sentences owned by a user."""
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    sentences = models.ManyToManyField(Sentence, blank=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

**Update 2**: Output of `pip freeze -l`

```
asgiref==3.4.1
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
certifi==2021.10.8
cffi==1.15.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.10
cryptography==36.0.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==4.0.1
django-allauth==0.47.0
django-filter==21.1
djangorestframework==3.13.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
idna==3.3
importlib-metadata==4.10.1
Markdown==3.3.6
oauthlib==3.1.1
psycopg2==2.9.3
pycparser==2.21
PyJWT==2.3.0
python-dotenv==0.19.2
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2021.3
requests==2.27.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
soupsieve==2.3.1
sqlparse==0.4.2
urllib3==1.26.8
whitenoise==5.3.0
zipp==3.7.0
```

Comment: Have you maybe set `SITE_ID = 0` in your settings?

Comment: Can you add your model definition to the question please.

Comment: @AKX Nope. It's set to 1.

Comment: Huh, so you're not actually using site anywhere yet? Something wants it though. Could it be you need to add the default site record in as part of a migration? Never used sites myself so a little unsure ...

Comment: @michjnich You can see from the traceback that the error is happening in [`create_default_site`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0f6946495a8ec955b471ca1baaf408ceb53d4796/django/contrib/sites/management.py#L11).

Comment: @michjnich I'm also using `django-allauth` which requires `django.contrib.sites` to be installed.

Comment: @AKX that implies `SITE_ID` is not set, which OP has confirmed it is ... weird.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Can you add the output of `pip freeze -l` to the post too? I think this could be a library bug, since it implies that Django is trying to set the counter value to an out-of-range number.

Comment: @AKX Updated the question with the output.